# Unity 5 import package

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have installed Unity 5 personal version and trying to follow tutorials.
One of the tasks is to right click on assets and import a character package, however, when I right click on assets and point to `import package`, all I see is `custom packages` without any other options like the guy has on the tutorial.
For example: `character, effects, environments, vehicles, etc.`

Is there something that I forgot to install, or do I need to enable it somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you download and install Unity, be sure to check the box for `Standard Assets` during installation.

Answer (score 1):

> Try downloading the Standard Assets installer from their website.
>
> 1. http://unity3d.com/get-unity/download?ref=personal
> 2. Click additional downloads
> 3. Click Standard Assets

<sub>Credits to [Klockrent](http://answers.unity3d.com/users/544383/klockrent.html).</sub>

Answer (score -1):

I think you forgot to install standard assets.
Go to the following link,

https://unity3d.com/get-unity/download/archive

And select standard assets for your version.

After downloading the standard assets, just install it.
It will resolve your issue.